# Unable to Deskew an image using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I followed [this tutorial by Adrian Rosebrock](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/) on Deskewing the images and created a function like:

```
def deskew(image):
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray) # invert colors white numbers black background

    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
   
    if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    
    else:
        angle = -angle


    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),
        flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)


    cv2.putText(rotated, "Angle: {:.2f} degrees".format(angle),
        (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    return image,"{:.3f}".format(angle)

    
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
skewed = imutils.rotate(image,14.74)
corrected,angle = deskew(skewed)

plt.imshow(corrected)
plt.title(f"Corrected by:{angle}")
plt.show()
```

and got angle=0.0

Image is this:

[image]

Actually the original image is already skewed. I have all my pictures like this (little or no spacing in border and text : cropped pictures of questions from text book). I want to perform OCR on this. How can I de-skew the pictures?

Comment: Deskew only works well if all lines of text are parallel. In your case there is considerable distortion and the angle of all lines are not the same.

Comment: So there is no method to Deskew the question images. nothing at all? No other approach?

Comment: @Deshwal, I too had a problem in correcting the skew in images. I solved it using the minAreaRect method itself but it was too lengthy.

Comment: @TarunChakitha Can you please explain it or show some code? After 7 months, I'm back at it again.

Comment: @Deshwal Yes I have provided the links in my answer. please let me know if they work for your cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach to correct the 2d-skew in images. It is simple and naive but works fine for almost all images containing a considerable amount of text. It does not correct the 3d distortion. It works best only with images containing only the 2d skew. And might not work for images containing graphics(like your chemistry molecular structures), but give it a try because your images are so similar to mine.

The ***correct skew*** function in [this Script](https://github.com/SaiTarunUppari/OCR/blob/master/OCR.py) is my approach.

If you are still not satisfied I have a better idea.

[Deskew library](https://pypi.org/project/deskew/) is the best for correcting the 2d skew in images.

Hope this solves your problem.